# Maverick - OSX dock auto hides when connecting a display through hdmi?

Tags: macos, display, dock

When I connect my TV to my laptop, the Dock starts to auto hide. Is there a way to keep the dock in its before I connect an external display? Also, when go to  > Dock, the auto hiding is off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the new multi-display handling in Mavericks where the Dock can be made to show on both displays. It's not actually 'auto-hiding' hence why the auto-hiding is still disabled.

To go back to the old multi-display method, go to System Preferences → Mission Control and uncheck Displays have separate Spaces.

Comment: Is there a way to make the dock show on both displays without auto hiding?

Comment: @Gasim Not currently.